# Jquery toggle requires two clicks after first click

Tags: jquery, toggle

I move two divs (open) when clicking, when the user clicks, I want the rest to reset. (It looks pretty clear in my fiddle)

The first time I run the script and click the objects, it works flawless, but if I continue clicking, it requires two clicks to function. I've tried functions involving .click() and e.preventdefault, but none of it worked. I've already spend to much time on this, so I hope someone can help me out on this.

Many thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/baZDy/

```
$("#schoenen").toggle(
```

function () {

```
//schoenen
$("#rood_een").animate({'left':'480px'});
$("#rood_twee").animate({'top':'120px'});

//casual
$("#oranje_een").animate({'left':'240px'});
$("#oranje_twee").animate({'top':'120px'});

//schoenen
//$("#rood_een").animate({'left':'360px'});
//$("#rood_twee").animate({'top':'0px'});

//ceremonie
$("#blauw_een").animate({'left':'120px'});
$("#blauw_twee").animate({'top':'240px'});

//communie
$("#groen_een").animate({'left':'240px'});
$("#groen_twee").animate({'top':'360px'});
```

},
function () {

```
$("#rood_een").animate({'left':'360px'});
$("#rood_twee").animate({'top':'0px'});
```

});

$("#casual").toggle(
function () {

```
//casual
$("#oranje_een").animate({'left':'120px'});
$("#oranje_twee").animate({'top':'0px'});

//casual
```

// $("#oranje_een").animate({'left':'240px'});
    //$("#oranje_twee").animate({'top':'120px'});

```
//schoenen
$("#rood_een").animate({'left':'360px'});
$("#rood_twee").animate({'top':'0px'});

//ceremonie
$("#blauw_een").animate({'left':'120px'});
$("#blauw_twee").animate({'top':'240px'});

//communie
$("#groen_een").animate({'left':'240px'});
$("#groen_twee").animate({'top':'360px'});
```

},
function () {

```
$("#oranje_een").animate({'left':'240px'});
$("#oranje_twee").animate({'top':'120px'});
```

});

Comment: The `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` function is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle()` is deprecated in latest version

> This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in
>   jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle()
>   that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the
>   event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

For alternative see [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490957/what-is-alternative-to-use-after-jquery-1-9-removed-togglefunction-function)

Comment: So I cannot use it anymore... or what?