# jQuery .toggle() Alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently, jQuery removed `.toggle()`, and I don't know how to toggle text within a button.  And yes, I've looked around this forum for an answer, but none were adequate.

Here is my code:

```
$("#show").click(function () {
if($(this).text() == "Show") {
    $(this).text() == "Hide";
    alert("Fill fields");
} else {
    $(this).text() == "Show";
    alert("Clear fields");
}
});
```

Explanation:

- When #show is clicked, execute anonymous function.
- if the text is "Show", change to "Hide"
- then, alert "Fill fields"
- Else, change text to "show"
- alert "Clear fields"

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zArU9/).

Comment: `$(this).text() == "Hide";` is checking for equality. It shoudl be `$(this).text("Hide");`

Comment: I have rolled back your edit, because an edit should not change the meaning of a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is alternative to use after jQuery 1.9 removed .toggle(function,function)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490957/what-is-alternative-to-use-after-jquery-1-9-removed-togglefunction-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setter of `.text()` is like this:

```
$(selector).text('text here') // this is setter
```

and not

```
$(selector).text() == 'text here'; // this is comparison
```

So full code:

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    if($(this).text() == "Show") {
        $(this).text("Hide");
        alert("Fill fields");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Show");
        alert("Clear fields");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zArU9/1/)

You can shorten it with ternary operators if you want to:

```
$('#show').click(function(){
   $(this).text(function(_, text) { return text == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'; });    
});
```

Comment: `$(this).text(function(_, text) { return text == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'; });`

Comment: @zerkms well, I know that, but should I confuse OP with that?

Comment: nope, just an alternative for the whole community :-)

Comment: @zerkms That is too confusing, why use that method?

Comment: @Matthew: it's a matter of preference

Comment: @Matthew actually, you'll find ternary ifs easier than manual if and else... You'll get to know that later...

Comment: @zerkms Ohh okay.  Why don't my alerts call and the action loop?

Comment: @Matthew you can do that as well, before `return`ing

Comment: @AmitJoki Wouldn't `$(this).text() == "Show"` be `$(this).text("Show")`?  When I changed it to that, the alerts don't work

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely you were looking for toggle event alternative; you could pass n functions to it and they would be fired in succession as you clicked.

Check [jquery-toggleclick.js](https://github.com/maniator/jQuery-toggleClick/blob/master/jquery-toggleclick.js). toggleClick jQuery plugin will do just that.

**Usage**:

```
$("#show").toggleClick(fillFields, clearFields);
```

Then you can set the text in the appropriate function

Answer (score -3):

I checked jquery documentation. Toggle is still there.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: No, it was depreciated in 1.8

Comment: To clarify, `toggle()` which shows/hides content is still there. `toggle()` which attaches event handlers has been removed.

Comment: attaches event handlers - depreciated in 1.8 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/
shows/hides content
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/