# jQuery toggle between same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 items which should be toggle-able. So when an item is visible, and I click on another item, the one I clicked should open. The other one should close.

Any suggestions on how I could do that?

I've tried to add this to my jQuery file, but nothing want to toggle then...

```
var sliderContent = $(this).next('.groupf-more');
        $('.groupf-more').not(sliderContent).hide();
        sliderContent.toggle();
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.groupf-more').hide();
$('.groupf-title').toggle(function() {

    $(this).closest('li').find('.groupf-more').slideDown();
    $(this, '.toggle-item').removeClass('groupf-title');
    $(this, '.toggle-item').addClass('groupf-title-active');

    return false;

},
function() {

    $(this).closest('li').find('.groupf-more').slideUp();
    $(this, '.toggle-item').removeClass('groupf-title-active');
    $(this, '.toggle-item').addClass('groupf-title');

    return false;

});
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="toggle" style="margin-right: 1%">
    <li class="toggle-item">
        <div class="groupf-title">Title</div>
        <div class="groupf-more">Content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-item">
        <div class="groupf-title">Title</div>
        <div class="groupf-more">Content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The two-function form of `.toggle` was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: you could work with an active class (which you are already doing - but don't remove groupf-title, just add active as a second class). when clicking on an item you give it the active class. then you cycle through all of your items and close all which don't have the active class.

Comment: What is `$(this, '.toggle-item')` supposed to do?

Comment: @barmar: Above 1.9 i think... jQuery is not my thing, I've been testing around. Everything worked with that script, except the toggle between the divs. Thanks for replies so far!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490957/what-is-alternative-to-use-after-jquery-1-9-removed-togglefunction-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $mores = $('.groupf-more').hide();
  var $items = $('.toggle-item');

  var $titles = $('.groupf-title').click(function() {
    var $more = $(this).next('.groupf-more').slideToggle();
    $mores.not($more).slideUp();
    var $title = $(this).toggleClass('groupf-title groupf-title-active');
    $titles.not($title).removeClass('groupf-title-active').addClass('groupf-title')
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.groupf-title {
  color: red;
}
.groupf-title-active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="toggle" style="margin-right: 1%">
  <li class="toggle-item">
    <div class="groupf-title">Title</div>
    <div class="groupf-more">Content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle-item">
    <div class="groupf-title">Title</div>
    <div class="groupf-more">Content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although, my classes are wrong, this toggle works! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.groupf-more').hide();
$('.groupf-title').click(function() {

    $('.groupf-more').slideUp();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.groupf-more').slideDown();

    return false;

});
```