# jquery animate function -click one div toggle another

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have this jquery function that always gives me the second function every time i click. How can I stop this?

I have a navbar that has 3 links and for every link i have a .contentDiv with different id's. Every time somone clicks on one of those links the toggle function takes place; hiding all .contentDiv expect the one that is linked to that link. and an animation of sliding to the left occurs to that one .contentDiv

HTML:

```
.navbar
ul
    li
        a.about(href='#') About
            span
            span
    li
        a#portfolio(href='#') HOME
            span
            span
    li
        a(href='#') Contact
            span
            span
.contentDiv#portfolioContent
                    .title About
                    .content
                        .fse
                            p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

CSS:

```
    .contentDiv {
    transform: skew(45deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    left: 300%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    font-size: 500%;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #EAEBED;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 43%;
    left: 3%;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-family: Raleway;
    color: #EAEBED;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:scroll;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.about').click(function () {
    $("#aboutContent").toggle(
        function() {
            $("#aboutContent").animate({left: "115%"}, { //coming out of hiding
                duration: 2000
            });
        }, function() {
            $("#aboutContent").animate({left: "300%"}, { //back into hiding
                duration: 2000
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Are you saying only the second one is being called, but you actually want both of the handlers to run?

Comment: Is this the way toggle function works?

Comment: yes only the second toggle function is running when click on the ".about" but i want both to run.

Comment: do you want to call the another function of click or do you want to stop toggle function?

Comment: i want it to toggle between the functions when clicked on, but its only calling the second function.

Comment: Hmm... you're using it the same way they reference in in the api https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ not sure why it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `clickToggle` function and use it to toggle between functions on click:

Source: [jQuery click / toggle between two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions/21520499#21520499)

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$('.about').clickToggle(function() {
  alert("First handler for .toggle() called.");
   $("#aboutContent").toggle("Slow");
}, function() {
  alert("Second handler for .toggle() called.");
   $("#aboutContent").toggle("Slow");
});
```

```css
#aboutContent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="about">
  CLICK
</button>

<div id="aboutContent">
  123123123
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this on the .about, which is a link("a" tag), and it would make the .about disappear.

Comment: i will put up all of the HTML, CSS and jquery that i have so that way you can see what is happening.

Comment: @Mus3Math hm maybe try my updated solution, create a function so you can use anywhere later.

Comment: just upload the rest of the code, so you can take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

```js
var c = 1;
$('.about').click(function() {
  $("#aboutContent").toggle(function() {
    c++;
    if (c % 2 == 0) alert("1")
    else alert("2");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
try this:
<button class="about">
  click
</button>

<div id="aboutContent">
  code..
</div>
```

Comment: this one works as well, but the other one is one that suits my needs. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery toggle() function to toggle between two specified functions is deprecated in v1.8  and removed in 1.9 as mentioned [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). toggle() is now used to alternate show() and hide() only.

So you'll have to create a customized toggle plugin as mentioned in the other answer or you may check this [stack overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490957/what-is-alternative-to-use-after-jquery-1-9-removed-togglefunction-function).